# Crash when pushing "this" pointer into array.

Tags: c++, crash, this

I am trying to get all leaf nodes from my tree structure. Code is from ue4, so  just treat "TArray" like a normal std::Vector.

```
TArray<BSPNode *> * BSPNode::getLeafNodes()
{
    TArray<BSPNode *> *  collected = new TArray<BSPNode*>;
    collectLeafNode(collected);
    return collected;
}

void BSPNode::collectLeafNode(TArray<BSPNode *> * leafNodes)
{
    if (leftNode == nullptr && rightNode == nullptr)
    {
      if (leafNodes != nullptr)
      {
        if (this != nullptr)
            leafNodes->Add(this);
      }
    return;
    }

if (leftNode != nullptr)
    leftNode->collectLeafNode(leafNodes);

if (rightNode != nullptr)
    rightNode->collectLeafNode(leafNodes);

    return;
}
```

debugger shows that acces violation appear in

```
    if (leftNode == nullptr && rightNode == nullptr)
```

Debugger output: 
[callstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXu15.png) line 95 is `if (rightNode != nullptr)` line 82 `if (leftNode == nullptr && rightNode == nullptr)`

and [variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWmfr.png).

I have totally no idea why program crashes, is it related in using "this" pointer? Thanks in advance :).

Comment: your `this` pointer is on undefined memory. It is probably a node that has been deleted. If your application is small, you can try to print under the debugger the deleted nodes to see if/when the parent of this has been deleted.

Comment: Undefined? So it's not nullptr and non valid at same time? How can I print in debugger deleted nodes? It's small structure, something about 10-20 nodes. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is not nullptr but non valid. You can set a breakpoint on the node destructor (by expliciting it) and set a print message every time the instruction under the breakpoint is executed.

Comment: YIKES, i didn't expect that non nullptr pointer can be broken. You are awesome, I just initialize nodes with nullptr, and now everything works, thanks :).

Comment: ok, don't hesitate to post a minimal complete code that anybody can compile ;-). And you can write (default or not) constructors in `struct` that initialize all the fields, just to avoid many undefined behaviors.